# Count rows that don't match between two tables within a group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables, each with a `user_id`, and `group_name` columns.

E.g.

```
table1:

| user_id | group_name1|
------------------------
|    1    |   'groupA' |
|    1    |   'groupB' |
|    2    |   'groupA' |
|    1    |   'groupA' |
------------------------


table2:

| user_id | group_name2|
------------------------
|    1    |   'groupL' |
|    2    |   'groupL' |
|    3    |   'groupL' |
|    4    |   'groupN' |
|    1    |   'groupN' |
|    3    |   'groupN' |
------------------------
```

I'm trying to create a distribution of counts between the number of times a user in table2 shows up in table1, but do this within a group.

For the example above, I'd get

```
| times_show_up | number_of_users | group_name1 | group_name2 |
---------------------------------------------------------------
|      0        |       1         |    groupA   |    groupL    |
|      1        |       1         |    groupA   |    groupL    |
|      2        |       1         |    groupA   |    groupL    |
|      0        |       2         |    groupB   |    groupL    |
|      1        |       1         |    groupB   |    groupL    |
|      2        |       0         |    groupB   |    groupL    |
|      0        |       2         |    groupA   |    groupN    |
|      1        |       0         |    groupA   |    groupN    |
|      2        |       1         |    groupA   |    groupN    |
|      0        |       2         |    groupB   |    groupN    |
|      1        |       1         |    groupB   |    groupN    |
|      2        |       0         |    groupB   |    groupN    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

To explain some rows as further example:

For row 1, the user with user_id = 3 in groupL shows up 0 times in groupA. 
 For row 2, the user with user_id = 2 in groupL shows up once in groupA.  And for row 3, the user with user_id = 1 in groupL shows up twice in groupA.

Although in this example a person shows up up to a maximum of 2 times, in the real data this number is some arbitrarily large number that I don't know ahead of time.

Similarly for the other groups if I filled all that out correctly.

I've come up with a query that can do all of this except counting the 0s, that looks like this:

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(user_id) AS num_users,
        times_show_up,
        group_name1,
        group_name2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS times_show_up,
            group_name1, 
            group_name2
        FROM
            table1
        RIGHT JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, group_name2 FROM table2)
        USING(user_id)
        GROUP BY user_id, group_name1, group_name2
    )
    GROUP BY times_show_up, group_name1, group_name2
```

Unfortunately this won't return the 0 counts in the `times_show_up` column, and I haven't figured out a solution that can accomplish this without a lot of subqueries. One possible method is to just run subqueries to grab all the 0s for all combinations of all groups, and then just `UNION` those rows to the rest of the table.  But I want to avoid approaches that include subqueries for each possible group1, group2 combination since the number of groups is very large.

Some limitations include that `partition by` on this data set tends to run out of memory so I want to avoid it.  **Updated requirement:** In addition, using CROSS JOIN at the individual user level (so cross joining table1 direclty to table2 without grouping up rows first) doesn't work because each table has 10s of millions of rows.

Finally, rows with 0s in the `number_of_users` column don't have to show up (it's fine if they do since they can be removed with a simple `WHERE`, but are not necessary, if it helps with the query)

---

**UPDATE:**

I was able to come up with a query that can generate the zeros while only requiring a single query for each group_name1, rather than a single query for each group_name1, group_name2 combination.  I'm adding it to the question in case it helps come up with answers with yet fewer queries, since it's still the case that the number of groups in table 1 could be upwards of 20+ which means 20+ queries added via `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
        times_show_up,
        COUNT(user_id) AS num_users,
        group_name1,
        group_name2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS times_show_up,
            group_name1, 
            group_name2
        FROM
            table1
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, group_name2 FROM table2) t2
        USING(user_id)
        GROUP BY user_id, group_name1, group_name2
    ) t1
    GROUP BY times_show_up, group_name1, group_name2) t9
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT
       0 AS times_show_up,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_id IS NULL 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_users,
       'groupA' AS group_name1,
       group_name2
     FROM
       table2
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_name1 = 'groupA') t1
     USING(user_id)
     GROUP BY group_name2)
     UNION ALL
    (SELECT
       0 AS times_show_up,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_id IS NULL 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_users,
       'groupB' AS group_name1,
       group_name2
     FROM
       table2
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_name1 = 'groupB') t1
     USING(user_id)
     GROUP BY group_name2)
     --- ORDER BY group_name1, group_name2, times_show_up
```

Comment: Why is user `1` in `groupA` twice?

Comment: @CHP . . . Tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: @The Impaler - This is intended.  A bit hard to explain without going into what the groups mean, but in general, Group A is grouping not users, but user sets.  And here we want to count the number of sets a user in group A is part of.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks, doing this in BigQuery and added a tag per your suggestion, though I should be able to convert to BQ if I get the general logic, which hopefully doesn't rely on specialized functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and ended up being relatively simple

```
#standardSQL
SELECT times_show_up, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) number_of_users, 
  group_name1, group_name2
FROM (
  SELECT COUNTIF(a.user_id = b.user_id) times_show_up, 
    b.user_id, 
    group_name1, group_name2
  FROM table1 a
  CROSS JOIN table2 b
  GROUP BY user_id, group_name1, group_name2
)
GROUP BY times_show_up, group_name1, group_name2
-- ORDER BY group_name2, group_name1, times_show_up
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row times_show_up   number_of_users group_name1 group_name2  
1   0               1               groupA      groupL   
2   1               1               groupA      groupL   
3   2               1               groupA      groupL   
4   0               2               groupB      groupL   
5   1               1               groupB      groupL   
6   0               2               groupA      groupN   
7   2               1               groupA      groupN   
8   0               2               groupB      groupN   
9   1               1               groupB      groupN
```

> ... rows with 0s in the number_of_users column don't have to show up

Note: I follow this rule as looks like you plan to eliminate them anyway in case if result has such

> Update for ... each table has 10s of millions of rows.

Try below "optimized" version

```
#standardSQL
SELECT times_show_up, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) number_of_users, 
  group_name1, group_name2
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(IF(a.user_id = b.user_id, cnt, 0)) times_show_up, 
    b.user_id, 
    group_name1, group_name2
  FROM (SELECT user_id, group_name1, COUNT(1) cnt FROM table1 GROUP BY user_id, group_name1) a
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, group_name2 FROM table2) b
  GROUP BY user_id, group_name1, group_name2
)
GROUP BY times_show_up, group_name1, group_name2
```

I don't have relevant data to test though whether this will help or not for your specific data

Comment: This is interesting.  I was afraid of using cross join on the raw user data because there are 10s of millions per table.  I gave it a shot anyway and so far the query hasn't crashed, but it's been running for 15+ minutes now and my sneaking suspicion is that it will exhaust compute resources before it completes.  

If it works and there's no simple way to build a faster query (e.g. if all other versions require a subquery for each group1, group2 combination) I will accept this answer since it's a neat solution.  But the sloppier queries at least run in ~1 minute.

Comment: let's see if this will make an end w/o erroring :o) I will look into this query again in the morning to see if this can be optimized. but honestly I think it should succeed as is even for 10M+

Comment: Still hasnt' crashed but after 83 minutes I stopped it :D   This was on a smaller data set so I can only imagine what will happen on a larger data set.  I'll add the 'no cross joins at the individual user level' to the requirements of the question :)

Comment: default query timeout is 6 hours. but it might be too much to wait for your case o( just saw your update  - yes, I think this is right direction for optimization - pre-aggregate both tables first.

Comment: Right, even if it completes, 83 minutes for a smaller query is not worth it since I can get it ot compelete in ~1-3 minutes with just using subqueries for each of the group1, group2 zeroes.  For example my initial query that computes eveyrthing correctly except the zeros completes in ~1 minute

Comment: i ran your initial query against sample data and I didn't get expected result. but i can be wrong as i didn't spent much time. anyway - i will check this one again in the morning . it is midnight right now in LA and I still have some other work to do :o)

Comment: Here is a fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78bf1f/4

Ignore the rows with null in group_name1, I can easily get those to go away by replacing Right join with Inner join (or a where statement).  If you do, then you will see that this query is generating all rows where num_users > 0 (as desired), except those where where times_show_up = 0 (the problem I'm trying to solve)

Comment: @CHP - added "optimized" version :o)

Comment: This still takes a very long time, so far running for 30 minutes and it hasn't completed, and i suspect it won't scale well with larger data sets either (only feeding in 3 groups for the test, instead of like 20)  :)  The updated query I posted by contrast completes in 20 seconds for 3 groups.  Maybe I was too naive to think this could be done fast without additional queries.  It just seems odd though that only the 0s are causing problems, I feel like there's gotta be some logic I'm missing for including them with a single query that doesn't cross join at the user_id level.

Comment: I ended up canceling it since it took over an hour, but I'll accept the answer since it meets the original question, and nothing more efficient has come up.  I'll post my query as a separate answer for people with similar size data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the strategy.

1. Use `cross join` to generate the rows.
2. For this purpose, get the groups using `count(distinct)`.
3. Generate the `times_show_up` using a derived table.
4. Aggregate `table1` and `table2`
5. Join this all together.

Here is the query:

```
select g1.group_name1, g2.group_name2, tsu.times_show_up,
       coalesce(t12.cnt, 0) as num_users
from (select distinct group_name1 from table1) g1 cross join
     (select distinct group_name2 from table2) t2 cross join
     (select 0 as times_show_up union all
      select 1 union all
      select 2
     ) tsu left join
     (select t1.group_name1, t2.group_name2, count(*) as cnt
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
      group by t1.group_name1, t2.group_name2
     ) t12
     on t12.group_name1 = g1.group_name1 and
        t12.group_name2 = g2.group_name2 and
        t12.cnt = tsu.times_show_up;
```

You may want `count(distinct user_id)` instead of `count(*)` in the subquery, if your data really does have duplicates.

Comment: I don't think this will work because it seems be hardcoding the 0, 1, 2, whereas it might be anything in the actual data.  A person might show up 1000 times or some other number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Mikhail Berlyant meets the original requirements of my question.  Unfortunately because it relies on a cross join at the user_id level, and there are 10s of millions of user IDs, it takes long to complete for my specific use case. So I'm providing the following answer, which is faster, but **does** require an additional query for each group in table 1 (but not for each combination of group1 and group2), making for a less concise query that can potentially balloon beyond the limits of BigQuery query size if the number of groups is very very large.

This approach is preferred if you can programmatically generate the queries for each group and have fewer groups with millions of users, whereas the answer by @Mikhail Berlyant should work well for situations when there are many more groups with a small number of users each, and in cases where the query generation is not done programmatically and you have to write each one for each group.

````
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
        times_show_up,
        COUNT(user_id) AS num_users,
        group_name1,
        group_name2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            user_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS times_show_up,
            group_name1, 
            group_name2
        FROM
            table1
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, group_name2 FROM table2) t2
        USING(user_id)
        GROUP BY user_id, group_name1, group_name2
    ) t1
    GROUP BY times_show_up, group_name1, group_name2) t9
    # Each subsequent query being UNIONed corresponds to a group in table 1
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT
       0 AS times_show_up,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_id IS NULL 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_users,
       'groupA' AS group_name1,
       group_name2
     FROM
       table2
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_name1 = 'groupA') t1
     USING(user_id)
     GROUP BY group_name2)
     UNION ALL
    (SELECT
       0 AS times_show_up,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.user_id IS NULL 
           THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_users,
       'groupB' AS group_name1,
       group_name2
     FROM
       table2
     LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_name1 = 'groupB') t1
     USING(user_id)
     GROUP BY group_name2)
     --- ORDER BY group_name1, group_name2, times_show_up```
````